# How can I make a vpn network login the default behavior for logging into Windows?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, login

To login to the machine, I have to login to our domain. When I am at work, the unauthenticated wireless permits access to the domain. However, the internet is not available until I connect via the vpn. From home, I have to connect via the vpn first, then I can login to the domain.

I have successfully setup a network logon with the vpn (following the directions found [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/1ee7325e-3bb7-4cea-89b4-787713260bf3)). And for the most part it works correctly. (There is an issue with logout/login I haven't figured out just yet).

As I currently have to Switch User and select the Network Login button, I'd like to know if it is possible to have the network login the default behavior when logging into the system. This is mostly a usability issue than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

With Win7 it should do this
 automatically after the first reboot...

Try this from [this thread:](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/35575-domain-logon-screen.html)

> ...you can set the default logon
>   domain in group policy so that it
>   defaults to the domain you want. You
>   can still find out the local station
>   name by clicking on the link that
>   tells you about logging on to
>   different domains.
>
> It is in: Computer config > Admin
>   templates > System > Logon : Assign a
>   default domain for logon
>
> With this little tweak and: Computer
>   config > Windows settings > Security
>   Settings > Security options:
>   Interactive Logon: Don't display last
>   username
>
> It makes the Vista/Win7 logon
>   perfectly usable in a domain with less
>   hassels than XP and staff attempting
>   to log on locally. I actually like it
>   better but do wish that you could
>   customize it.

Comment: No, I don't believe that is what I'm looking to answer. I've updated my question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: You want to alter the default behavior of the logon prompt to automatically select a network/domain logon, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: I will double-check this to see if I missed something in your instructions.

Comment: Well, this sort of works. Unfortunately, I still have to go select the network login on the bottom-right of the login screen. I was hoping to have this actually be the default user login prompt. I don't believe its sufficiently intuitive as it stands right now.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have to log into the domain, you probably don't have to be **connected** to the domain to log in. That's because Windows "caches" your domain credentials. You should still be able to log into your_domain.com (instead of "local computer") even while working remotely.

Or am I misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: Although that is true, to have internet access I must authenticate on the VPN. If I can force it to reconnect every time that'd be great. Single-sign-on and all that jazz :)